# ESLint indent and operator-linebreak

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

We have our ESLint config inherit from airbnb's config.

Despite the indent rule being turned on, for some reason, this is allowed:

```
let a = some * math
* operators;
```

even though I would expect it to require the following (extra indentation for emphasis):

```
let a = some * math
    * operators;
```

Indentation linting works as expected everywhere else.

For example, linting will complain about the indentation here:

```
let c = somefunction(
parm
);
```

Is this a bug in ESLint, or is there a rule I need to turn on in my config? Nothing in indent's documentation seems to apply, and I don't see any other rules that seem relevant.

Thanks!